Is it ok to rename default database postgres?
I found recently that on one of our systems uses default postgres database as it's... well, database.
I want to move all the data to another db in the same cluster. But the database is relatively large and the system is somewhat 24/7.
Maybe I could simply rename the postgres db? And then create another one named postgres and use it as maintenance db.
This sounds like a not safe thing to do and my intuition says I should stick to traditional dump/restore methods.
Or maybe I'm overreacting?

It is just fine to rename the postgres database and create a new one. The database will have a non-standard object ID, but that shouldn't matter at all.
